# How to check whether a column exists and then copy it?

Tags: sql-server

For example, I want to copy column1 to column2. So I tried:

```
IF(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column1') = 1
UPDATE table1 SET column2 = column1
GO;
```

The SQL Server complain that the column1 doesn't exist, while there is IF before the UPDATE.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write a statement like this, because the parser will check the entire statement to make sure it is valid before it will let it run.   So even though you use the IF, the entire statement isn't valid if there is no `column1`.

The way you can make this work is to use dynamic sql after the IF:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT ...) = 1
  BEGIN

  DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'UPDATE table1 SET column2 = column1';
  EXEC (@sql);

  END
```